# How can I use embedded Firebird in my Delphi application

Tags: delphi, firebird, delphi-xe3, firebird2.5

My Delphi XE3 application used Interbase components to connect to a Firebird 2.5
SuperServer.

I started a new project to isolate the problem, and tried to connect to my software database. The results follows.

1 - I can connect to the database using TIBDatabase normally.

and I want to deploy it to use embedded Firebird my question is:

1. can I use Interbase components to connect to a embedded Firebird?
2. if yes then how can i do it?
3. if not then is there any free Firebird components?

Comment: AnyDAC components are now distributed as FireDAC, dunno if they can be purchased for XE3, OTOH XE3 Pro to XE4 upgrade costs only $50.
You may also use commercial FIB+ of http://www.devrace.com/ru/fibplus/ . And you may try non-TDataSet approaches like mORMot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can I use Interbase components to connect to a embedded Firebird?

By default you can use Interbase components to use Firebird.

> if yes then how can i do it?

You must change the name of firebird client library, in common word.

- In dbExpress and Firebird server edition => use fbClient.dll and
  dbxFb.dll in client side of program.
- In dbExpress and Firebird embedded edition => change name of
  fbEmbed.dll to fbClient.dll and use dbxFb.dll in client side of
  program(fbClient.dll and dbxFb.dll).
- With IbExpress and and Firebird server edition => change name of
  fbClient.dll to gds32.dll.

In addition, Daniel Magine writed an article about Firebird and dbExpress.
http://www.embarcadero.com/rad-in-action/database

> if not then is there any free Firebird components?

You can use [ZEOS.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zeoslib/%E2%80%8E)

**UPDATE**
In Firebird 3:

> When  does not contain a network protocol but just the database name, the Remote provider rejects it and the Engine12 provider comes to the fore and tries to open the named database file. If it succeeds, we get an embedded connection to the database.

Comment: `c:\RAD Studio\9.0\source\data\dbx\Data.DbxFirebird.pas` -> `constructor TDBXFirebirdProperties.Create(DBXContext: TDBXContext);
` -> `Values[TDBXPropertyNames.VendorLib] := 'fbclient.dll';`
You can just write correct program, that'll load `fbEmbed.dll` rather than cripple global OS state be substituting filenames. That would also work in practice on most occasions, but that reminds me of programs removing all Windows locales but Russian, instead of learning proper font management. Example of doing this for MySQL: http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/2010/11/dbx-without-deploying-dbxdrivers-ini/

Answer (score 3):

While Interbase and Firebird are sill almost compatible API-wise, I recall some have reported having problems when using IB components (which come with Delphi) when connectiong to Firebird. These components are officially for Interbase only and thus you can be sure that over time the situation will get worse (more incompatible), not better. So I would recommend using components which officially support Firebird. I personally use [UIB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uib/) which is free, but there is others as well (both free and commercial).

Comment: I used UIB too, but i patched it to load DLLs with a proper path, sane for distributing your EXE with FB-E DLLs